# basic java programming. How to increases the wins property by one?

Tags: java

```
public int compare(Player p) {
    //compare to check who has won the last round.
    if (this.lastBase > p.lastBase || this.lastTie > p.lastTie)
        return 1;
    else if(this.lastBase < p.lastBase || this.lastTie < p.lastTie)
        return -1;
    else                                                                                                              
        return 0;
    }

    public void win() {
        //increases the wins property by one.but it seems it's wrong, and I have no idea how to increase with respect to the compare method.
        if(this.compare(p) = 1 || this.compare(p)=-1)
            wins++; 
    }

    public int getWins() { 
        return wins;
    }
```

I'm a java beginner, thank you very much if you can give me some advice!

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but your question as currently written is a bit lazy since you've just given the sketch of a question and dumped your code. Please consider putting a little more effort into your question. Give the details on just what this code does, just where you're stuck.

Comment: `this.compare(p) = 1 || this.compare(p)=-1` should be `this.compare(p) == 1 || this.compare(p)==-1`

Comment: Remove unwanted white space and make the code more compact

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Your comment should be accepted as answer (the advice is there).:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
   public void win(Player P) 

  {

    if(this.compare(p) = 1)

    this.wins++;
    else{
    p.wins++;
    }

    //increases the wins property by one.but it seems it's wrong, and I have no idea how to increase with respect to the compare method. 
  }
```

If the plyer of this referece wins then it increments the class attribute wins of first player by one else the attribute of the object Player P is incremented by one.